# Lightning Web Component: Use Balkan's OrgChartJs library

Tags: lightning-web-components, third-party

I would like to use Balkan's OrgChartJs library to make a visualization in a LWC.  However, it is not a static resource, as it is designed to call 'new OrgChart(...);'.  Is there a way I can use this Library?

Comment: @glls I don't see how the linked question answers this one?

Comment: @sfdcfox, Imo - user is asking if and how he can use a 3rd party library which is  explained in the linked post. (why it would work or not, and where to check)